# Trying to pass data from a component to other - REACT JS

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass data from a component to other component by

```
<Link to={{
          pathname: `payment/${id}`,
          state: {
            data: data,
          },
```

```
 const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    description: "",
    startDate: "",
    endDate: "",
  })
```

```
    setInputs({
      description: inputs.description,
      startDate: startDate,
      endDate: endDate,
    })
```

```
<Link to={{
          pathname: `/caravan-rezerve/ek-urunler/${id}`,
          state: {
            data: inputs,
          },
        }}
```

On the other component

```
const { data } = this.props.location;
```

I'm getting TypeError: props is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the documentation to help you use a Link tag for passing the props and how to use it in the component. https://ui.dev/react-router-pass-props-to-link

Do check the link and then try it again. If you still face issues, please do tell.